# Javascript: Set Width of DIV by Window Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to set the width of a div to the same value as the window height.

I tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".rt-container").style.width = $(window).height();
</script>
```

But it's not working. Maybe because I'm an absolute beginner with javascript.

How can I achieve it (by using jquery)?

Comment: Learn how to debug javascript using your console, jQuery object has no property `style`, DOM node has

Answer (score 2):

You can change `css` styles like this, use the method `.css()` with `option` and `value` as parameters and add the "px" to value, as mentioned in comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".rt-container").css("width",$(window).height() +"px");
</script>
```

Comment: px is optional here, anyway +1

Comment: @A.Wolff is that because it defaults to px?

Comment: @SamCreamer Passing number to css method, jQuery convert it to string for some specific properties: `// If a number was passed in, add 'px' to the (except for certain CSS properties)
   if ( type === "number" && !jQuery.cssNumber[ origName ] ) {
    value += "px";
   }`  These are excluded properties: `"columnCount": true, "fillOpacity": true, "fontWeight": true, "lineHeight": true, "opacity": true, "order": true, "orphans": true,  "widows": true,
  "zIndex": true,
  "zoom": true`